# Mediasoup получение контроля над громкостью микрофона react/typescript/js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webrtc

Получаю вот такой вывод активного микрофона от сервера по каждому клиенту.

Задача в том как получить контроль громкости по name над каждым участником.  react typescript

```
Object { event: "active_speaker", producer_id: "c0cb0e04-e31a-4902-9f74-4d59fba2de0c", user_id: 1707394536890, volume: -43, name: "houndy" }

Object { event: "active_speaker", producer_id: "e3f4abf7-119e-4ded-9e23-13ca0de8bc34", user_id: 1707397033151, volume: -45, name: "hetr" }
```